# How can I change my dimension for input of neural network?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, conv-neural-network, dimensions

I want to implementation of bellow model for speaker verification from speech. After reading wav file from folder, I am using log Mel filter bank energy for extract features. Now, I want to use this feature as input but as describe in the figure, input feature must be 80, but 1430 is for me. Here I must to use batch size for  segmentation the features or I have to use dimension reduction technique? (I'm using python and pytorch for implementation)

[image: speaker verification model]

My code for  4 first layers:

```
class NeuralNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_class):
        super(NeuralNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(1, 80, T),
              BatchNorm2d(4),
              ReLU(inplace=True),
              MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2))
        
       self.conv2 = nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(128, 40, T),
             BatchNorm2d(4),
             ReLU(inplace=True),
             MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=1))

       self.conv3 = nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(128, 40, T),
             BatchNorm2d(4),
             ReLU(inplace=True),
             MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=1))

        self.conv4 = nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(128, 40, T),
              BatchNorm2d(4),
              ReLU(inplace=True),
              MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=1))           

       self.conv5 = nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(128, 20, T = flatten),
             BatchNorm2d(4),
             ReLU(inplace=True),
             MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2))
```

But dimension of feature extracted from audio is not 80, I don't know how can I change it to 80.

Comment: Do you have code that you have tried? Most of the time, the specification of a layer is dynamic and will automatically adjust to your input at compile. For example, Dense(10), takes in arbitrary data (batch_size x N) and will output (batch_size x 10), adjusting the internal kernel automatically.

Comment: So Thanks, I am editing my post and adding a code. But I don't know is it true? or must be edit code?

Answer (score 0):

I am not as familiar with pytorch, I know more about tensorflow. But I can help you in reading the documentation https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html. It appears pytorch requires to know the input and output dimensions. In general, a `conv2d(I,O,(k1,k2))` would modify input data of dimensions `B x I x H x W` and turn it into data like `B x O x (H-k1) x (W-k2)`; where `B` is the batch_size. You appear to have variables in the wrong place (for example, `T` appears to the be the width) and are missing the `BK` layer (I don't know what that is or what it does). It also appears that the paper is keeping the dimensions the same, so you need to use some padding, `padding="same"`. Notice also that the `kernel` does effect the input or output dimensions (which makes sense; look up how to blur an image by convolving with a Gaussian kernel). Your layers should look something like:

```
# (B x 1 x 80 x T)
nn.Conv2d(1, C, (3,3), padding="same")
# (B x C x 80 x T)
BK_layer # I don't know what this does but it appears to cut the height in half.
# (B x C x 40 x T)
nn.Conv2d(C, C, (3,3), padding="same")
# (B x C x 40 x T)
ResBlock # I don't know what this does but it appears to not change the dimensions. 
# (B x C x 40 x T)
nn.Conv2d(C, C, (3,3), padding="same")
# (B x C x 40 x T)
ResBlock 
# (B x C x 40 x T)
nn.Conv2d(C, C, (3,3), padding="same")
# (B x C x 40 x T)
ResBlock 
# (B x C x 40 x T)
nn.Conv2d(C, C, (3,3), padding="same")
# (B x C x 40 x T)
BK_layer 
# (B x C x 20 x T) # got cut in half again
ECAPA-TDNN
# S x 1
```

I don't know how the interaction of ECAPA-TDNN reaches `Sx1` dimensions; but it appears to involving some flattening and it sounds like it involves a merge layer with multiple stacks.

I left out the activation layers for simplicity. I highly recommend to read about "convolving" over an image with a kernel. Convolutional layers make a lot more sense when you understand how convolving over an image allows you to detect edges or blur images. The difference between "Gaussian blurring" and "NN Convolution layer" is that one is fixed (typically a button to use in GIMP or Photoshop) and the other is dynamic with an evolving kernel that changes as the network learns.

As you can see the input is expected to `1 x 80 x T`. I am unsure how you expect to fit your 1430 into that. There are a number of ways to get the form you want, from adding padding, to dropping values, using an additional layer, etc. For example, if 1430 was padded with 10 zeros at the end, it would be 1440, which can reshape to `1 x 80 x 18`.